# Lego connector, 2 pin, Vintage

Tags: identification, connector, plug

I have searched the forum and am unable to find reference so am asking what I hope is an unanswered question.

I have been tasked with getting an old (eighties / nineties) Lego collection back into action and I am stumped as to how to describe this 2 pin connector to be able to find a replacement.

It's 4.5 V and the pins are +/- 5 mm apart and +/- 4 mm round and protrude +/- 5 mm. They have splits (see picture).

Given the exorbitant price of a replacement complete cable I'd prefer to just replace the connector if possible.

Could anyone much wiser than me help with an identification or description so I can source a couple?

[image: Lego 2 Pin 4.6v Connector]

Comment: There are second hand ones available for not that much money: https://www.brickowl.com/catalog/lego-2-pin-electric-connector-rounded-narrow-with-cross-cut-pins

Comment: You should probably ask this at https://bricks.stackexchange.com/ instead (the Lego site), since it isn't obvious what kind of component this is. Could be a potentiometer, could be something else.

Comment: wow! that's extermely vintage, the ones I had in the 70s had 90 degree taps.  another vote for bricks.

Comment: @ lundin, it's a 2 pin non-polarised plug, with "banana" style pins.  pin pitch is the same as lego stud pitch YCLIU

Comment: The uneven slitting in the screw leads me to describe it as "hand made". 4mm pins are readily available (a bit longer than that) known as "banana plugs". Would 2 individual plugs be acceptable?

Comment: Many thanks to all for the helpful suggestions.

Comment: Hi, I realise you are new here (welcome!) but on Stack Exchange approach the "Your Answer" box is for answers to the original question *only*, so your post has been converted into the comment above. Please see [here](/help/someone-answers) for the article from the [help] which explains what to do. At the moment you don't have enough points to add visible "upvotes", but please consider "[accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234)" the answer which was the best for you (currently there is only one *answer*, the others are comments) to effectively mark the topic as complete. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's not available on its own. It's only available as part of the cable P/N bb81c96, which is found in these LEGO kits: 960, 912, 404-1 970-1 870, 901-1, 4-5.

https://www.toysperiod.com/lego-set-reference/parts/electric/wires/bb141ac96_electric-wire-45v-with-two-lt-gray-2prong-type-1-connectors-96-studs-long/